# c++: int overflows when it is smaller than INT_MAX

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I wrote a code like below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

long long int N, K;



int main() {
    cin >> N >> K;

    long long int result = 0;
    int IntResult = 0;

    for (long long int i = K; i <= N + 1; i++) {
        result += 1 + (N + 1 - i) * i;
        IntResult += 1 + (N + 1 - i) * i;
    }

    cout << result % (1000000000 + 7) << endl;
    cout << IntResult % (1000000000 + 7) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I input "141421 35623", this code outputs below.

```
141421 35623
220280457
619089693
```

The correct answer is "220280457". The result of int is wrong.

I put cout in a for loop and checked IntResult's value.

Then I found that IntResult became negative value in a for loop. It's overflowed!

But why? The max value of int is "2147483648". It's greater than "220280457".

And the process in for loop is just an addition, so I can't understand why it is overflowed.

Please help me!

Comment: The value of `IntResult` is clearly overflowing. Just look at how often you iterate the loop and multiply that by `N`, which is much less than what you are adding, but still more than the limit. The end result doesn't tell you anything, since you are taking a modulo operation on the result. I don't understand what is unclear to you. Can you please clarify?

Comment: What the fool I am! I forgot a modulo! Thank you all who gave responses. I'm so embarrassed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, the expression `1 + (N + 1 - i) * i` (which is evaluated as a `long long int`) **quickly and frequently** becomes greater than `INT_MAX`, and this causes integer overflow when you try to add it to the (`int`) `result`.

Adding a quick 'check' to your code, as shown below, will demonstrate this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    cin >> N >> K;
    long long int result = 0;
    int IntResult = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (long long int i = K; i <= N + 1; i++) {
        // Check for intermediate overflow potential...
        long long int lli = 1LL + (N + 1LL - i) * i;
        if (lli > INT_MAX) cout << lli << " (" << ++count << ")"  << endl;
        result += 1 + (N + 1 - i) * i;
        IntResult += 1 + (N + 1 - i) * i;
    }
    cout << result % (1000000000 + 7) << endl;
    cout << IntResult % (1000000000 + 7) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on my platform (32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long long int`) with your given inputs (`141421` and `35623`), the "overflow check" line actually happens **88,498 times**! Here are the last three lines of output:

```
...
2147524241 (88498)
220280457
619089693
```

Furthermore, even though the above-checked addend may not, in itself, overflow an `int`, the result of adding it to the existing (potentially non-zero) value in `result` could still do so. Indeed, changing the 'check' line to this:

```cpp
if ((lli + result) > INT_MAX) cout << lli << " (" << ++count << ")"  << endl;
```

shows that the loop overflows on ***every*** iteration!

Answer (score 1):

You overflow on first iteration.

```
1 + (N + 1 - i) * i
```

Is smaller than

```
(N - i)*i
```

First iteration:

```
(141421-35623)*35623
```

Whoops already overflow, which is UB in signed integers.

```
IntResult % (1000000000 + 7)
```

Happens afterwards, and has no meaning as IntResult contains a unknown value.